# Swagger XML comments file - missing comments

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle, xml-comments

I'm self-hosting Swagger documentation for my Web API 2 API with Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0

I'm enabling Swagger in my Startup.cs as follows

```
config.EnableSwagger(c => 
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "AUDM API");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "commentsfile1.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "commentsfile2.xml");
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        }).EnableSwaggerUi(/*x => x.DisableValidator()*/);
```

The swagger ui shows up just fine, listing all my endpoints and methods. But, there's zero documentation.. all my comments and remarks in the controllers are missing, as are the

When I debug and look at the two fully qualified paths to my XML files, they resolve just fine at runtime, so I'm assuming that should be fine.

The two xml files come from different libraries, but that shouldn't matter, should it.. the files are there so IMHO they should be used. Is there a way to troubleshoot why the XML files are not getting picked up?

Comment: Yes, that should have worked... Do you have a sample project on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be missing a slash `\` in the path, try this:

```
c.IncludeXmlComments(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\commentsfile1.xml");
```

here is a sample from the official project:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L261

Comment: I've tried with the additional slash, but same behavior. And at least in my case, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ends with a slash (or rather.. two as usual with .NET strings).
I actually rewrote my code to generate the path using System.IO.Path.Combine, but it's the same story. I'm even checking if the generated path exists using System.IO.File.Exists.. and it reports true.

Comment: @user1537915 Can you upload a sample project to github reproducing your issue?

Comment: Funny enough, I was on my way to a customer who might want to see the swagger GUI, and all of a sudden I started getting comments. I suppose something was off in my compilation configuration. If I ship the .xml documentation files, I even get the comments in my release configuration.

However, it fails with a nice FileNotFoundException on my .xml files when I run my app as a service. I take it that AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is c:\windows\system32 - but, that doesn't explain why copying my xml files to that directory doesn't solve the issue.